# Good way to defer this processing (javascript example)

Tags: javascript, web-services

I'm having a deferment issue that I wondering if there is a good way to handle

Here is my code:

```
getFullAddressFromId: function (contactId) {
            var contact;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/WebServices/FormOverview.asmx/GetFullAddressfromId",
                    data: { id: contactId},
                    success: function (result) {
                        contact = result;
                    },
                        error: function (err) {
                            _local.sendNotification.apply(this, ['Failed to load address information', 'Error']);
                    }
                });     
            };

            return contact;     
        }
```

Problem here obviously is "contact" is not loaded by the time it hits the return statement as the webservice has not finished running.

How can I defer the return from this function (getFullAddressFromId) to wait for the webserbvice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use asynchronous programming techniques.

```
var getFullAddress = function(id, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(result) {
      // stuff
      callback(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Or use [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) with jQuery 1.5+

```
var getFullAddress = function(id) {
  return $.ajax({
    ...
  });
}

getFullAddress("22").done(function() {
  // handle result
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your expect a callback function as its second argument and call that callback when the AJAX request succeeds:

```
getFullAddressFromId: function (contactId, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/WebServices/FormOverview.asmx/GetFullAddressfromId",
        data: { id: contactId },
        success: callback,
        error: function (err) {
            _local.sendNotification.apply(this, ['Failed to load address information', 'Error']);
        }
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getFullAddressFromId: function (contactId) {
            var contact;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/WebServices/FormOverview.asmx/GetFullAddressfromId",
                    data: { id: contactId},
                    success: function (result) {
                        contact = result;
                    },
                        error: function (err) {
                            _local.sendNotification.apply(this, ['Failed to load address information', 'Error']);
                    },
                    async: false
                });     
            };

            return contact;     
        }
```

But you don't want to use this because the browser window will most likely hang waiting for the web server. Go for the asynchronous ones.